# Return a row with the best fields in pyspark GroupedData

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to aggregate a `GroupedData` object into a `Row` with the best attributes (not `None` or highest `timestamp`) for a `Dataframe` like:

```
╔═══════╦═══════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ group ║ timestamp ║ value1 ║ value2 ║ value3 ║
╠═══════╬═══════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ a     ║       111 ║ None   ║ None   ║ None   ║
║ a     ║       222 ║ a      ║ None   ║ None   ║
║ a     ║       333 ║ b      ║ 1      ║ 1.1    ║
║ a     ║       444 ║ None   ║ None   ║ 2.2    ║
║ b     ║       111 ║ c      ║ None   ║ 3.3    ║
╚═══════╩═══════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

I want to have a result `Dataframe` like:

```
╔═══════╦═══════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ group ║ timestamp ║ value1 ║ value2 ║ value3 ║
╠═══════╬═══════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ a     ║       444 ║ b      ║ 1      ║ 2.2    ║
║ b     ║       111 ║ c      ║ None   ║ 3.3    ║
╚═══════╩═══════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

Ideally I want to create a different logic to aggregate every column. For example `min` for `timestamp` but `max` for `value3`.

Is this possible in `Dataframe`s?

Thanks,

Comment: when you say you want `min of timestamp` column for group `a` your result should have `111` not `444`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SparkSQL` will actually do exactly what you want it to do and ignore null values when aggregating a column. As an example, let's consider the following dataframe:

```
df = sc.parallelize([("a", 1, None), ("b", None, 5), ("a", 2, None), ("b", 0, 7)]).toDF(["A", "B", "C"])
```

that looks like this:

```
+---+----+----+
|  A|   B|   C|
+---+----+----+
|  a|   1|null|
|  b|null|   5|
|  a|   2|null|
|  b|   0|   7|
+---+----+----+
```

You can aggregate using different functions like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.groupBy("A").agg(F.min(F.col("B")), F.max(F.col("C") ))
```

and get what you expect (ignored null values expect when this is the only value, and different aggregator functions):

```
+---+------+------+
|  A|min(B)|max(C)|
+---+------+------+
|  b|     0|     7|
|  a|     1|  null|
+---+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below to achieve your result

```
# create data frame like below to match your grouped data frame
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('a', 111, None, None, None), ('a', 222, 'a', None, None), ('a', 333, 'b', 1, 1.1), ('a', 444, None, None, 2.2), ('b', 111, 'c', None, 3.3)],  ('group', 'timestamp', 'value1', 'value2', 'value3'))

# import necessary functions 
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

# apply group by and agg functions on the data frame
df1 = df.groupBy('group').agg(f.min('timestamp').alias('timestamp'), f.max('value1').alias('value1'),  f.max('value2').alias('value2'), f.max('value3').alias('value3'))

# show the result data frame
df1.show()

# +-----+---------+------+------+------+
# |group|timestamp|value1|value2|value3|
# +-----+---------+------+------+------+
# |    a|      111|     b|     1|   2.2|
# |    b|      111|     c|  null|   3.3|
# +-----+---------+------+------+------+
```